# Assign value from firebase callback

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to access my firebase DB, retrieve a value and then assign it to a variable to be used later in the code.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    projectId: "",
    storageBucket: "",
    messagingSenderId: ""
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);
database=firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('test');
var firebaseMsg ='';

ref.on('value',function(snap){
//console.log(snap.val());
firebaseMsg=snap.val();
});

console.log(firebaseMsg);
```

my firebase database looks like this:

```
    {
  "test" : "Hello from my database!"
}
```

the console log produces an empty string, it seems that the assignment in the ref.on callback doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because queries to the Firebase database are asynchronous: your `console.log()` executes **before** the callback function returned by the `on()` method is returned.

The following will work:

```
ref.on('value',function(snap){
   //console.log(snap.val());
   firebaseMsg=snap.val();
   console.log(firebaseMsg);
});
```

as you have probably noticed since there is a `console.log(snap.val());` line that you commented out.

This means that, for example, you can only update your application UI (to reflect a change in the database) from within the callback function.

Comment: Ahh I see, would it be possible to use the async/await schema to make it so I can force the retrieval of my data before I console.log it? I have tried this: 

`var firebaseMsg='';
async function queryFirebase(){
ref.on('value',function(snap){
  firebaseMsg=await snap.val();
  
  });
}

queryFirebase();
console.log(firebaseMsg);`

But i get the error 'await only valid in async function'

Comment: If you want to use async/await use the `once()` method, which is asynchronous an returns a promise, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once. The `on()` method is listener that returns a callback function.